# Find the 2 lowest number Index in a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I want to find the index of 2 lowest number in a vector in R. Vector looks like:

```
vec = c(3300, 2220, 2220)
```

I know how to find the minimum. I have used the below function to write the minimum.

```
Minimum should come out to be 2200, 2200.
minIndex <- which(vec == min(vec ))
```

Answer is *`minIndex = 2*.

**Desired Answer** is *minIndex= 2 3*

Comment: `vec = c(3300, 2220, 2220); which(vec == min(vec )) #[1] 2 3` gives me your **desired answer**

Answer (score 1):

`order` gives the index of the lowest, the next to lowest and so on so take the first two elements of it:

```
head(order(vec), 2)
## [1] 2 3
```